# Why is taking the sum of residues required?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

[image]

As you see in the solution, I am confused as to why the sum of residues is required.

My question is the sum:

$$(4)\cdot\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{\coth(\pi n)}{n^3}$$

**Question #1:**

-Why is the beginning $n=1$ the residue is for **all** $n \in (-\infty, \infty)$ so the beginning of the sum should be $n=-\infty$ right?

**Question #2:**

-Why are they taking the sum anyway? The residue is simply $\displaystyle \frac{\coth(\pi n)}{n^3}$ why is the sum required there?

Comment: 1.) this is due to symmetry reasons: The poles for for positive and negative numbers are essentially the same. This gives you a factor of $2$ and a sum over positive numbers. The same applies for the complex poles
2.) No, you have an infinite number of residues, if you're pushing the contour to infinity. According to the residue theorem you have to sum them all up!

Comment: @tired, I see. So in the beginning it is: $$=2\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} f(n)$$ then that implies that: $$= 4\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)$$?? $(2)$ the residue theorem states that: $$\oint_{C} f(z) dz = (2\pi i)(\sum \text{res} f(z))$$ Where is the $2\pi i$ there?

Comment: 1.) $$ 2 \sum_{n=-\infty, n\neq 0}^{\infty}f(n)+f(0)=4 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)+f(0)$$
2.) I also wondering where the $2 \pi i$ is gone, what defintions they use for residue theorem and the calculation of the residue?